# Does Robotium test an Android apk which are installed in /data/app location without having the source code?

Tags: android, automation, robotium

I am new to Robotium. I want to test my mobile application using Robotium . I want to know whether it is possible to test the app with only having .apk file without having the source code of app , having only the source code of test app using Robotium . If possible for these kind of apps may i know the process to do it...which means how we can follow the process.....

Note : I want to use only my app(.apk) and my test app(.apk)                                                         with these two apks whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go [here](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials) to the Robotium tutorial page and look into the [Test Android Calculator APK Black Box Testing](http://robotium.googlecode.com/files/TestAndroidCalculatorAPK-BlackBoxTesting-V2_0.pdf) pdf for an example on how to do blackbox-tesing with Robotium.

Of course you need the source code of **your** app in order to prepare the APK file. Otherwise using Robotium to make automated inputs to arbitrary APK's is not possible.